# linq question: querying nested collections

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, linq-to-xml

I have a **Question** class that has public List property that can contain several **Answers**.

I have a question repository which is responsible for reading the questions and its answers from an xml file.

So I have a collection of Questions (List) with each Question object having a collection of Answers and I'd like to query this collection of Questions for an Answer (ie by its Name) by using Linq. I don't know how to do this properly.

I could do it with a foreach but I'd like to know whether there is a pure Linq way since I'm learning it.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer related to a given question or for a specific answer that could be related to any question?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

To find an answer.

```
questions.SelectMany(q => q.Answers).Where(a => a.Name == "SomeName")
```

To find the question of an answer.

```
questions.Where(q => q.Answers.Any(a => a.Name == "SomeName"))
```

In fact you will get collections of answers or questions and you will have to use `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, or `SingleOrDefault()` depending on your needs to get one specific answer or question.

Comment: I would expect the questions would want to be kept, so something more like: ... SelectMany(q => q.Answers.Select(a => new { A = a, Q = q }).Where(qa => qa.A.Name == "SomeName") would be a better fit.

Comment: You can always get back to the question with answer.Question - no need to introduce a anonymous type.

Comment: @danbruc: No such property listed in the Q

Comment: You are right! I had some ORM in mind, but the question mentions only a class.

Answer (score 41):

```
from question in Questions
from answer in question.Answers
where answer.Name == something
select question // or select answer
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Use the SelectMany and First/FirstOrDefault (if you are needing one value)

```
List<Questions> questions = //initialization;
var someAnswer = questions.SelectMany(q=>q.Answers)
                          .First(a=>a.Name =="MyName");
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems you could use something like this:

```
var query = from q in questions
            from a in q.Answers
            where a.Name == "Answer Name"
            select a;
```